# can i implement facebook/twitter login in reddit login api

Tags: php, iphone, ios, json, reddit

i am developing iPhone Application and i want to implement Sign in through **Facebook/twitter** account is it possible user can sign in Reddit through Facebook/twitter account.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, the accounts aren't linked in any way.  You'll have to ask the user to create a new reddit account (which is possible with the api).